# Raspberry PI and log4j

Tags: java, linux, shell, logging, log4j

I have a Java program running in a raspberry pi with a USB device using log4j. Whats is hapenning is that I am getting System.out.println and putting in a file with this command in a SH file:

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file./log4j.properties -server -jar MySystem.jar /dev/USB >> /tmp/log.txt 2>&1
```

I removed all the system.out.prinln from the code and changed for info and error from log4j and now I did not manage to log it into the file.

Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Comment: Your log4j is not configured properly.

Comment: BTW, are you aware of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I'm unsure if that is all that relevant to Alvp's problem, but a good link nonetheless.

Comment: My log works on my PC but its not getting the info and erros into raspberry.

Answer (score 0):

I had the log4j parameter wrong. In this case, I just left the log4j normally configured in the system and I removed it from this script, so then I have the "prints" and also the logs from log4j.

```
java -server -jar MySytem.jar /dev/USB
```